# Select Device Compatible With Target Android 4.1

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am starting the final testing on an app I am working on. I am just now testing compatibility with different Android versions. Now when I try to run my app on a version of Android older than 4.1 the AVD manager says to select a device compatible with Android 4.1. It wont show me any of the AVD's I created with older Android versions. I can only select the AVD with 4.1 In my manifest file I have this declared:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" 
          android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
```

Which to my knowledge should allow my app to run on Android versions from API 7 up to API 16. But it will not show me anything older than 4.1. I tried starting an AVD with an older version from the AVD manager and then install my app. It lets me install it but there is a red X over it saying its not compatible. In the app I am using the default text color and transparent buttons with a black background which shows up on 4.1 with white text. But in older Android versions the text is black. Other than the uses-sdk line in my manifest file I dont know of anything else that would affect this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is your `Project Build Target` in IDE? I think it is set to 16.

Comment: the project build target it set to 4.1. So I have to drop that to 2.1 for this to work?

Comment: yes as `IDE` shows `AVDs` according to the build target set for your project.

Comment: Ok I did that but now have some compiler errors because it appears that these items are not available on 2.1 which makes sense. However shouldnt I be able to use things only available in newer versions and use a version check to avoid running new code on old devices? Like if (deviceVersion > 3.0) {use this code} else if (deviceVersion  < 3.0 {use that code}?

Comment: to use new `Features` in older versions of android you can use http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html and If you want a method only runs on specific OS then you can always check the OS in your code. using this class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html

Comment: Yea I have some version checking code in there already and I am using the support library. I guess I'm asking because I was doing a version check for the settings. If it was 3.0 or newer I used a PreferenceFragment to do the settings and preferences. Now with the build version set at 2.1 it shows a compiler error because PreferenceFragment is not available in 2.1. Shouldn't I still be able to use PreferenceFragment since I'm doing a version check first?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15182/discussion-between-jason-crosby-and-m-mohsin-naeem)

Comment: Was this issue resolved with the chat discussion? If so an answer would be helpful!

Comment: Starting the emulator before running the app in eclipse allows it to be picked in the Android Device Chooser.